# Read data from file in a Controller method to be multithread safe (Spring RestController)

Tags: spring, spring-restcontroller

I`ve read that REST controller is multithreaded If I handle reading and parsing data from file
How do I need to implement the method to be multithread safe ? or the next example is ok and Spring take care about the method to be multithread safe

Assume that try-catch is implemented perfectly

```
@Controller
public class MyController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/data")
    public String getFileData(final String path){
        String str = null;

        try{
            str = "ReadAndParseDataFromFileLocatedAtPath";
        }catch (Exception e){

        }

        return  str;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no multithreaded problem in your demo. Every request to invoke the method is separated in Controller.